# Freeze a program created with Python's `click` pacage

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze, python-click

I've got a command line program that uses Python's [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) package. I can install and run it locally, no problem with:

```
pip install --editable . # (or leave out the editable of course)
```

Now, I'd like to create an executable file that can be distributed and run standalone. Typically, since I'm in a Windows environment, I would use one of `py2exe`, `pyinstaller` or `cx_Freeze`. However, none of these packages work.

More specifically, they all generate an executable, but the executable does nothing. I suspect this problem is because my `main.py` script doesn't have a `main` function. Any suggestions would be very helpful, thanks in advance!

Can reproduce the issues with code copied from [here](http://click.pocoo.org/5/setuptools/).

**hello.py**

```
import click

@click.command()
def cli():
    click.echo("I AM WORKING")
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
name="hello",
version="0.1",
py_modules=['hello'],
install_requires=[
    'Click'
],
entry_points="""
[console_scripts]
hello=hello:cli
""",
console=['hello.py']
)
```

If someone could supply a working **setup.py** file to create an executable and any other required files, that would be much appreciated.

From the console:

```
python setup.py py2exe
# A bunch of info, no errors
cd dist
hello.exe
# no output, should output "I AM WORKING"
```

Comment: Did you try adding a `main` function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I much prefer [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commits?author=stephenrauch) to the other alternatives, so I will cast an answer in terms of [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

#### Starting click app when frozen

You can detect when your program has been frozen with pyinstaller, and then start the click app like:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    cli(sys.argv[1:])
```

#### Building an exe with pyinstaller

This simple test app can be built simply with:

```
pyinstaller --onefile hello.py
```

#### Test Code:

```
import sys
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument('arg')
def cli(arg):
    click.echo("I AM WORKING (%s)" % arg)

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    cli(sys.argv[1:])
```

#### Testing:

```
>dist\test.exe an_arg
I AM WORKING (an_arg)
```