# Freeze a Python `click` application with subcommands using PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, python-click

I was hoping to freeze a Python CLI made with [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) using [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090083/12220645) which makes it work with click commands, unfortunately it doesn't work for applications with subcommands.

I've got the following code to demonstrate the issue:

In cli.py

```py
import sys

import click


@click.group()
def bar():
    pass


@bar.command()
def baz():
    click.echo('yo')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        bar(sys.argv[1:])
    else:
        bar()
```

I run the following `pyinstaller` command:
`pyinstaller --noconfirm --name bar --clean "cli.py"`

And I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests\bar\cli.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "click\core.py", line 722, in __call__
  File "click\core.py", line 696, in main
  File "click\core.py", line 621, in make_context
  File "click\core.py", line 1015, in parse_args
  File "click\utils.py", line 259, in echo
  File "click\_compat.py", line 577, in _safe_write
  File "colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 40, in write
  File "colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 141, in write
  File "colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 169, in write_and_convert
  File "colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 174, in write_plain_text
  File "click\_winconsole.py", line 180, in write
  File "click\_compat.py", line 63, in write
  File "click\_winconsole.py", line 164, in write
OSError: Windows error 6
[173704] Failed to execute script cli
```

I am using Python 2.7.13 on a Windows 10 OS.

I could not try `py2exe`, `cx-Freeze`, `briefcase` or the likes due to my job environment.

Has someone else stumbled upon this issue before ?

I'll try with argparse to see if I got the same issue.

Comment: It is trying to print the help.  Windows error 6 is *file handle invalid*.  How old (what version) is your colorama?

Comment: Thanks for your interest.
I was on colorama `0.3.9`.
I tried upgrading to `0.4.1`, but still have the same error.
I also tried with `argparse`, and there was no error. I suppose it comes from the fact `argparse` does no color handling ?

Comment: Yes, with that stack trace, seems likely to be an incompatibly in the color handling in Windows 10 when frozen.  I would also suspect (investigate) the very soon to be obsolete version of Python maybe causing some problems.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've done some more testing since.
I found [this issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3178) which details some workarounds, unfortunately none worked for me, I'll use argparse for the time being.
Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1):

So, after some more invstigation, it seems that Windows 10, Python 2.7.x and `kernel32.WriteConsoleW` don't bode well for pyinstaller.

Specifically, I found a [similar issue on pyinstaller's github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3178), in which some people detail the behavior of a Windows feature known as High Entropy for Bottom-up ASLR.

So there is 3 solutions or workarounds suggested in this link:

- Install, import and `enable()` `win_unicode_console`.
- Disable High Entropy on the generated executable properties.
- Upgrade to Python 3.

Check the link for more details, it's all black magic to me.

Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade to Python 3, couldn't find the high entropy setting, and the `win_unicode_console` trick did not work, so I'll stick with argparse.

The best solution would be to upgrade to Python 3 if possible.

Thanks Stephen for your help !